# Имитация отклика от удаленого сервиса

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core

Недавно устроился джуном на галеру, дали проверить и пофиксить баг с отправкой смс-кода для авторизации на сайте. Но вся фишка в том что сам удаленный сервис отключен для экономии средств и как такого мне полноценно не отдебажить и не посмотреть на работоспособность фичи.
Есть какой то способ сымитировать сервис и отклик от него чтобы пройти запрос и посмотреть есть ли реально баг или я просто убиваю время впустую?

```
var httpResponse = httpClient.GetAsync($"Url адрес{телефон}&text={тут смс-код}&sign={cот кого}").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Тут возвращается 401 ошибка ожидаемо и естественно в дальнейшем не проходит никакие проверки и как следствие не работает.

Comment: А у вас на гелере нет старших гребцов? Думаю стоит задать короткий вопрос им либо для начала поковырять что остальные рабы делают в таком случаи

Comment: а к кому мне обратиться в том случае если все (все до единого) старшие гребцы в отпусках?

Comment: к коду, я думаю ждуну не дадут задачу которую никто не делал

Comment: Слушайте, я задал вопрос, вопрос вполне вроде более четкий и понятный и суть вроде объяснил. Вы можете дать ответ на вопрос который я задал или так и будете давать ну совсем очевидные советы, до которых как ни странно я и сам дошел и в первую очередь пытался именно так и узнать ответ?

Comment: Такие вопросы лучше задавать внутри компании. Часто для таких платных сервисов есть эмуляторы. Спросите, может, у них такой есть

Comment: А у вас есть пример ответа данного сервера(возможно несколько в разных ситуациях), он наверное в json. Если нет, то и смысла никакого нет от подмены сервера. Но если есть, можно просто пропустить запрос и начать проверку как будто сервер отдал результат, я так понимаю главное проверить логику обработки ответа сервера ?. Вообще по хорошему это выполнять в юнит-тестах, класс с запросами должен быть замокан, а фейковый класс отдавать заранее готовый результат для проверки бизнес-логики

Comment: @Venen поняли что ответ точно не тут? а где-то там у вас на галере. Вам нужно посмотреть как люди симулируют такое поведение в тестах

Answer (score 0):

Если поможет, Postman умеет делать фейковый сервер https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/setting-up-mock/

Но я бы посоветовал изучать юнит-тесты и тестировать такие моменты через фейковые классы

Comment: Спасибо, учту.
Да надо изучать, но сейчас в изучении есть более приоритетные вещи, а все сразу не запомнишь